# Carmichael Number using Pari

Tags: math, pari

[image]

Trying to write Pari code to solve the above question.

Comment: What problems are you running into? Presumably you don't want us to simply write the code for you?

Answer (score 1):

I've got no experience in using Pari, but here's some useful advice:

`n` is Carmichael if and only if it is composite and, for all `a` with `1 < a < n` which are relatively prime to `n`, the congruence `a^(n-1) = 1 (mod n)` holds. To use this definition directly, you need:

1) An efficient way to test if `a` and `n` are relatively prime

2) An efficient way to compute `a^(n-1) (mod n)`

For the first -- use the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for greatest common divisors. It is most efficiently computed in a loop, but can also be defined via the simple recurrence `gcd(a,b) = gcd(b,a%b)` with basis `gcd(a,0) = a`. In C this is just:

```
unsigned int gcd(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    return b == 0? a : gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

For the second point -- almost the worst possible thing you can do when computing `a^k (mod n)` is to first compute `a^k` via repeated multiplication and to then mod the result by `n`. Instead -- use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), taking the remainder (mod `n`) at intermediate stages. It is a divide-and-conquer algorithm based on the observation that e.g. `a^10 = (a^5)^2` and `a^11 = (a^5)^2 * a`. A simple C implementation is:

```
unsigned int modexp(unsigned int a, unsigned int p, unsigned int n){
    unsigned long long b;
    switch(p){
        case 0:
            return 1;
        case 1:
            return a%n;
        default:
            b = modexp(a,p/2,n);
            b = (b*b) % n;
            if(p%2 == 1) b = (b*a) % n;
            return b;
        }
}
```

Note the use of `unsigned long long` to guard against overflow in the calculation of `b*b`.

To test if `n` is Carmichael, you might as well first test if `n` is even and return `0` in that case. Otherwise, step through numbers, `a`, in the range `2` to `n-1`. First check if `gcd(a,n) == 1` Note that if `n` is composite then you must have at least one `a` before you reach the square root of `n` with `gcd(a,n) > 1`). Keep a Boolean flag which keeps track of whether or not such an `a` has been encountered and if you exceed the square root without finding such an `a`, return `0`. For those `a` with `gcd(a,n) == 1`, compute the modular exponentiation `a^(n-1) (mod n)`. If this is ever different from 1, return `0`. If your loop finishes checking all `a` below `n` without returning `0`, then the number is Carmichael, so return 1. An implementation is:

```
int is_carmichael(unsigned int n){
    int a,s;
    int factor_found = 0;
    if (n%2 == 0) return 0;
    //else:
    s = sqrt(n);
    a = 2;
    while(a < n){
        if(a > s && !factor_found){
            return 0;
        }
        if(gcd(a,n) > 1){
            factor_found = 1;
        }
        else{
            if(modexp(a,n-1,n) != 1){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        a++;
    }
    return 1; //anything that survives to here is a carmichael
}
```

A simple driver program:

```
int main(void){
    unsigned int n;
    for(n = 2; n < 100000; n ++){
    if(is_carmichael(n)) printf("%u\n",n);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

output:

```
C:\Programs>gcc carmichael.c

C:\Programs>a
561
1105
1729
2465
2821
6601
8911
10585
15841
29341
41041
46657
52633
62745
63973
75361
```

This only takes about 2 seconds to run and matches the initial part of [this](https://oeis.org/A002997) list.

This is probably a somewhat practical method for checking if numbers up to a million or so are Carmichael numbers. For larger numbers, you should probably get yourself a good factoring algorithm and use Korseldt's criterion as described in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) on Carmichael numbers.